# How to bypass Tumblr's safe mode for RSS feeds

Tags: rss, tumblr

I use FeedDemon and I noticed that some Tumblr RSS feeds had stopped working recently. I thought it was random but I found out that all of the feeds that stopped working were for NSFW blogs.

It seems as though Tumblr's default safe mode filter is preventing RSS feeds from working for NSFW blogs. An example of how trying to access one of these feeds can be found [here](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=akiric.tumblr.com%2Frss), it appears as though the html for the 'safe mode' page is accessed instead of the RSS itself. Is there any way to make it so that these feeds can be accessed from a program such as FeedDemon?

UPDATE: it appears as though tumblr has changed their policy, as NSFW blog RSS feeds can now be accessed by my RSS reader without any modification done by myself.

Comment: This applies to many feed-reading apps. [anon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9153823/anon)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48025796/2014893) isn't helpful, as many feed apps (such as NewsBlur) don't fetch through one's local machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that Tumblr has made an exception for [Feedburner](https://feedburner.google.com/) ― all Tumblr RSS feeds can be retrieved by Feedburner, and from there they can be read by any aggregator.

The basic steps:

- Log in to / create account for Feedburner
- Get the url of the RSS feed for the blog in question (e.g., `https://staff.tumblr.com/rss`)
- Enter that url in the field under *"Burn a feed right this instant"*
- Review the presented options, then hit *Next »*
- Add the displayed Feedburner url to your feed reader

Answer (score -1):

Late answer but I had the same problem.  Feeddemon uses your internet browser you've set up in the options to check feeds - In my case Internet Explorer.  All you need to do is log in to tumblr using that browser and your feed will be able to access the nsfw rss feed.